# Visual studio 2017: click and change stackpanel color

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just started to program in visual studio 2017 (c#) and I'm trying to do a thing which I'd do in five minutes using other. I'm trying to build an application in which you can click on a button and change the color of a stackpanel. I've tried everything, but I can't imagine what to do! Can you advise me please?

Comment: I presume this is WPF, can you post some code? your .xaml for example

Comment: I've nothing yet... I'm just trying to understand something basic! 

Comment: Cool, keep at it WPF is great, especially when paired with MVVM so I'd look into that too.

Comment: This sounds like WPF indeed. Given the simplicity of what you are asking, I would advise you to go through some [WPF tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/) first.

Comment: especially  http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/stackpanel/ and http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/  you can also bind to a colour value like `Background={"Binding colour"}` and colour can be a string value `#ffffff`, not sure if this is bad practice though so look for other solutions too.